# Is it possible to make 1 generic method out of these 2 linq statements?

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 linq statements - currently in the middle of a switch block. The statements are below.

```
pwStartTime = lender.ApplicationWindows
.Where(w => w.Name == pwPeriod && w.EndTime.TimeOfDay > dateToCheck.TimeOfDay)
.Select(w => w.StartTime)
.FirstOrDefault();


pwStartTime = lender.TransferWindows
.Where(w => w.Name == pwPeriod && w.EndTime.TimeOfDay > dateToCheck.TimeOfDay)
.Select(w => w.StartTime)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

As you can see the only difference is that they refer to two different properties of "lender", however, all the elements used in the linq query are identical in "ApplicationWindows" and "TransferWindows", although they are not the same objects and each does contain other unique properties.

So, it it possible to return w.StartDate via one generic method?

Thanks in advance.

// Here's the 2 classes

```
public class ApplicationWindow
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}

public class TransferWindow
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public TimeSpan Cycle { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [XmlElement("Cycle")]
    public string CycleString
    {
        get { return XmlConvert.ToString(Cycle); }
        set { Cycle = value.IsNullOrEmpty() ? TimeSpan.Zero : XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the types of `lender.ApplicationWindows` and `lender.TransferWindows`?

Comment: Do ApplicationWindows and TransferWindows implement a common interface containing the fields you are using within the LINQ?

Comment: @AntP - I've added the 2 classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create an interface or abstract base class for `TransferWindow` and `ApplicationWindow`, defining the common properties? Then you can do something like this (assuming that `lender.TransferWindows` and `lender.ApplicationWindows` are lists of their respective classes - if not, modify method signature as appropriate):

```
public DateTime GetStartTime(IList<Window> windows, DateTime dateToCheck, string pwPeriod)
{
    return windows
    .Where(w => w.Name == pwPeriod && w.EndTime.TimeOfDay > dateToCheck.TimeOfDay)
    .Select(w => w.StartTime)
    .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If ApplicationWindows and TransferWindows implement a common interface then you can do the following;

```
public DateTime GetStartTime(IEnumerable<IWindow> windows, string pwPeriod, TimeSpan timeOfDay)
{
    return windows.Where(w => w.Name == pwPeriod && w.EndTime.TimeOfDay > timeOfDay)
        .Select(w => w.StartTime)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you are using LINQ To SQL then you can have these implement an interface by creating a partial class with the same name (and in the same namespace) as the two Window classes, saying that this implements the interface.

*I believe this should work, although I haven't done this in a while and I did it with VB.NET.*

Comment: Beat you to it ;) - Also, your `dateToCheck` variable doesn't exist.

Comment: Haha you did, I got really confused for a second when I saw (almost) exactly the same code wondering whether I'd somehow managed to post it twice. Great minds and all that :P - Thanks I edited the wrong part, thanks for that :)

Comment: Lol, thanks for the help guys - done and working - sorry there can only be 1 winner.

Answer (score 3):

An example of what you can do with interfaces:

```
pwStartTime = lender.ApplicationWindows.FirstOrDefaultDateTime(pwPeriod, dateToCheck);
pwStartTime = lender.TransferWindows.FirstOrDefaultDateTime(pwPeriod, dateToCheck);

public interface IWindow
{
    string Name { get; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; }
}

public class ApplicationWindow : IWindow
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}

public class TransferWindow : IWindow
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}

public static class IWindowExt
{
    public static DateTime FirstOrDefaultDateTime(this IEnumerable<IWindow> windows, string pwPeriod, DateTime dateToCheck)
    {
        return windows
                .Where(w => w.Name == pwPeriod && w.EndTime.TimeOfDay > dateToCheck.TimeOfDay)
                .Select(w => w.StartTime)
                .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

When you have method which aim at one interface, the prettier solution is to create extension method associated.